# JPA locks PESSEMISTIC_WRITE and FEW transactions

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions, locking

I'm using PESSEMSTIC_WRITE lock on my repository method. So that is locks my object till end of transaction. However, I've got a problem, within one endpoint, controller -> service -> I start transaction then I need to update my object and send message to kafka, after that I need within this method again update my object and send to kafka. So because it's one transaction, changes works only local in cache. But I need to save in database then send to kafka, then again change my object and save to database and send to kafka message, I can't use REQUIRES_NEW and create a new transaction in any way, because my object is locked. So how I can deal with it?
This lock is used in many parts of my project to fix parallel transactions.

Comment: I'm confused about the actual problem you're trying to solve. What do you mean by ' I need to save in database then send to kafka'? While your object is locked with a write lock, no one else can read the corresponding row, what does it matter if you save to database at that point or not? The changes will not be visible until the lock is released anyway

Comment: Alright, but I needed this slayer to save twice on lock object, on my opinion business is problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should create new service which will orchestrate the flow. That way you will be able to obtain the same pessimistic lock again in the second operation.

```
@Service
class OrchestratorService {
   ...

   void executeFlow() {
       someService.executeFirstOperationAndSendKafkaEvent()
       someService.executeSecondOperationAndSendKafkaEvent()       
   }
}
```

```
@Service
class SomeService {

   @Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)
   void executeFirstOperationAndSendKafkaEvent() {
       // any lock which obtained inside this method will be released once this method finishes
       ...       
   }

   @Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)
   void executeSecondOperationAndSendKafkaEvent() {
       // any lock which obtained inside this method will be released once this method finishes
       ...       
   }
}
```

There is one more important aspect worth to mention - sending kafka event is not transactional. `@Transactional` guarantees only that changes made to datasource will be transactional (in this case DB). Hence following scenarios are possible:

- if event is sent inside transaction scope, transaction can be rollbacked after succesfull sending kafka event
- if event is sent outside transaction commit, event sending may fail after succesful commiting transaction

Due to this nature it's good to split the process into few phases:

1. apply business changes in DB and store a flag in DB that kafka event should be sent, but it hasn't been done yet,
2. outside TX scope send event to kafka
3. in new TX change the flag that event has been sent, or schedule retry if there was error during sending event.

Comment: Thanks, I used similar code. I made service OrchestratorService not transactional and then SomeService made transactional, so every time I'm getting a new transaction.